# Delegates in class methods

Tags: objective-c, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

Let's say I have a class utility method which initialises an object, assigns its delegate and terminates.
Is there any way to keep that delegate around so that its not released causing a `message sent to deallocated instance` error?

I understand that delegate objects are weakly referenced by their delegating object to avoid a retain cycle (because the delegate object normally already has a strong reference to the delegating object).

In my case, my delegate object does not need to retain a reference to the delegating object after it is initialised (I think), so I avoid the the possibility of a retain cycle.

So my question is, is there any way in ARC for me to set the delegate of an object (a UIAlertView, for example) and specify that ***it retains*** the delegate, and frees it whenever it is not used anymore (when control reaches the end of the UIAlertView delegate method, for example)?

In case it helps, here's some example code:

```
+ (void)doSomethingWithCallback:(void(^)(void))callback
{
    UIAlertViewDelegateWithBlock *delegate = [UIAlertViewDelegateWithBlock new];
    delegate.callback = callback;
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Hello World." delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}
```

`UIAlertViewDelegateWithBlock` is this:

```
@interface UIAlertViewDelegateWithBlock : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic)void(^callback)(void);

@end

@implementation UIAlertViewDelegateWithBlock

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    self.callback();
}

@end
```

By the way, if the delegate object returns a strong reference to the caller, the delegate is retained and I get no errors. But having a variable used only to create a strong reference to the delegate is bad practice.

Comment: Hold callbacks (blocks) with reference of type (copy)

Comment: Using the example code, control never even reaches the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method. So I think it's the delegate that is being released, not the block.

Comment: `UIAlertView` doesn't retain its `delegate` property so your `UIAlertViewDelegateWithBlock` instance is being deallocated at the end of the `doSomethingWithCallback:` method.

Comment: BTW - there are plenty of block-based `UIAlertView` replacements [on github](https://github.com/search?q=uialertview&ref=cmdform).